Error when using hashtag in Data Validation in Excel
I am using Macbook Sonoma and am struggling to use # in the Worksheet. I have a dynamic column in a separate sheet called Lists that will have new values, so I am using the below formula to make sure new values are being captured dynamically, but the app is giving me an error. Any ideas what it could be?
Error I am getting:
Alert! The Source currently evaluates to an error. Do you want to continue?
Code: =Lists!$C$2#


Does that cell contain a spilled range?

@BigBen Hi! It's not giving me any "Spill" errors, the main sheet that I am using this formula on is also currently empty

Does Lists!$C$2 contain a formula returning a spilled range?

@BigBen oh I am sorry, first time using excel... No it doesnt

Then you can't use the spilled range operator #.

oh i see, how would you recommend I change the formula such that it updates the values dynamically?

I'd recommend using a table for your list data.

Currently in Excel we cannot specify a table or a dynamic list for data validation directly; we need to use a reference to a spill range (with #) or have a named formula that returns a list.
Using a table as BigBen suggested is a better way

Create a table (see the link in comment)
In Name Manger, add a name for the list, for example input_table and enter the table name from the step above in 'Refers to:' (for example =Table1)
Enter this name (input_table) as the source for data validation.


Without table - we need to select the rows with entries for validation; here for example if your entries will be in Lists!C2:C500

In Name Manager, enter a new name, input_list with a formula to select the entries from the first cell (C2) to the cell be before an empty one. =Lists!$C$2:INDEX(Lists!$C$2:$C$500, COUNTA(Lists!$C$2:$C$500))
As above, enter this name (input_list) as the source for data validation.


